# How to use global variables in function?

Tags: c++

I have a global variable, i want to use it in my function without parameter.
Example:

```
void main(){
int a[100];
earray();
}
void earray(){
//i want to use a[] here.
}
```

Comment: You *do not* have a global variable: `a` is local to `main()`.

Comment: `a` is local to `main`, its not global

Comment: Avoid using global variables. Use parameters.

Comment: T_T oh my mistake.. sorry sorry

Answer (score 7):

It's not a global variable (it's *local*). I assume you're trying to achieve something like the following:

Pass the local value to the function as a parameter (*better practice*)

For example :

```
void earray(int array[]){
    //array.
}

void main(){
    int a[100];
    earray(a);
}
```

Or, as a Global Variable (as you mentioned):

```
int a[100];

void earray(){
    //a.
}

void main(){
    earray();
}
```

Comment: Who the hell down-votes an answer that recommends an alternative and **better** practice!?

Comment: @StoryTeller, I guess people who fixate around the word *global* in the question and refuse to think of any suitable alternatives :-p

Comment: The question does say ‘*without parameter*’. (That's not to say that this answer is bad, but it *could* explain the down-votes.)

Comment: @Biffen, Very true! Guess I was in the wrong all along! Apologies, I've added both alternatives to my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

That is not a global variabel when you declare it in main.
Move it out of main like this:

```
int a[100];  // Global variable

void main(){
earray();
}
void earray(){
//i want to use a[] here.
}
```